# Antlr4: How can I match end of lines inside multiline comments?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have to create a program that counts lines of code ignoring those inside a comment. I'm a *newbie* working with Antlr, and after trying a lot, the nearest I came to a solution is this erroneous grammar:

```
grammar Comments;
comment         :   startc content endc;
startc          :   '/*';
endc            :   '*/';
content         :   newline | contenttext;
contenttext     :   CONTENTCHARS+;
newline         :   '\r\n';
CONTENTCHARS
    :   ~'*' '/'
    |   ~'/' .
    ;
WS              :   [ \r\t]+ -> skip;
```

If I try with `/*hello\r\nworld*/` the parser recognizes this, which is erroneous:

[image]

In order to count lines, the parser needs to detect newline characters, inside and outside multiline comments. I think my problem is that I don't know how to say "match everything inside `/*` and `*/` **except** `\r\n`.

Please, can you point me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use lexer modes. Once you hit `/*` enter the lexer mode for comments, and when you get to `*/` exit it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here exactly?

You wrote at the beginning: "I have to create a program that counts lines of code ignoring those inside a comment.";

But then you wrote: "In order to count lines, the parser needs to detect newline characters, inside and outside multiline comments.".

Comment: @Quepas I want to write a program that counts lines of code, ignoring whitespace, blank lines, and single line comments and multiline comments. In order to achieve that, I suppose the generated parser has to detect `newline` characters, so I can count them. But mixin the both things (detecting multiline comments without incrementing the line counter and detecting `newline`) is being surprisingly difficult to achieve.

Comment: @Kuma : Now I get it ! Check out the proposed solution and is it any good for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Let's simplify your grammar! In the grammar we will ignore whitespace characters and comments at the lexer stage (and the unwanted newlines at the same time!). For example the `COMMENT` section will match one line comments or multi-line comments and just skip them!

Next, we will introduce `counter` variable for counting `NEWLINE` tokens that are used only in `content` grammar rule (because `COMMENT` token is skipped so the `NEWLINE` token in it!).

Whenever we encounter a `NEWLINE` token we increment the `counter` variable.

```antlr
grammar Comments;

@lexer::members {
    int counter = 0;
}

WS : [ \r\t]+ -> skip;
COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' NEWLINE? -> skip;
TEXT : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' { {System.out.println("Newlines so far: " + (++counter)); } };

content: (TEXT | COMMENT | NEWLINE )* EOF;
```

Comment: Pretty nice idea. I didn't think about this possibility, thanks :).